# Ab Heute arbeite ich von München aus, is it correct

Tags: translation, english-to-german, verb

I like to say "From today I am working from Munich."

Bit of context, we are remote company and we have more locations, I want to let my co workers know that from today I will be working from Munich.

ChatGPT suggests that I should say "Ab Heute arbeite ich aus München.", but deepl says "Ab Heute arbeite ich von München aus."

I see that "ausarbeiten" means many things https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/ausarbeiten, but none of them is near to what I want to say. It means "work out" which is not right in this context.

My questions:

1. Is the meaning of "Ab Heute arbeite ich von München aus." -> "From today I am working from Munich."?
2. Why there is aus in this sentence, what's the meaning of ausarbeiten?

Comment: @RHa yes, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

ChatGPT is wrong, but DeepL is right.

> Ab heute arbeite ich von München aus.

That's indeed *From today, I work from Munich.*

It's not the verb *ausarbeiten* but adverbial *von X aus* combined with the verb *arbeiten* into a phrase, most commonly used as

> von zu Hause aus arbeiten

Note the preposition cluster *von zu* which makes this especially confusing. You can only understand this if you know the phrase. Otherwise you are lost.

Comment: To clarify: [von München aus] is a single directional adverbial (no phrasal verb here), the whole thing is unrelated to the particle verb [ausarbeiten]. At least in my understanding "phrasal verb" would mean the same thing as "particle verb".

Comment: To my understanding, a phrasal verb is a verb that takes a prepositional object, e.g. *auf etwas(Akk) warten*. It makes no sense to understand *auf etwas(Akk)* as a direction with *warten*, so this is clearly not an adverbial. One could discuss whether *von X aus* is an adverbial of origin (not: direction) as it's clearly usable as such with other verbs as well. I edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Verbs that take a PP object are called "prepositional verbs"; "phrasal verbs" are particle verbs, according to the source cited in https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partikelverb (fn. to lemma alternative  "Phrasales Verb").

Comment: @Janka thanks, first time I hear about adverbials. Is it "Ab Heute", or "Ab heute"?

Comment: It must be *ab heute*.